# how to call Jquery function from another Jquery function onchange event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My jQuery function has some selectbox code:

```
$("select#opt11")
.html(JSON_OPTION(geography,"Continent"))
.change(function(){
    $('td#1').find("#opt12,#opt13,#opt14,#opt15,#b11,#b12,#b13,#b14").remove();
    $('td#1').append('<br id="b11"><select id="opt12" style="width: 130px">           </select>');
    callService(this.value); }
```

This callService has to be another jQuery function like:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'URL/Services/rest/GWSWrapper/GetChartData',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            if(jqXHR.status==200){
                alert(jqXHR.status);
                $('#graphContainer').highcharts(data[0]);
            }
            if(jqXHR.status==500)
                alert("Fail");                      
        }
    });
});
```

Am not able to get the correct syntax for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your code in function and then call the function:

```
function callService(value)
{
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'URL/Services/rest/GWSWrapper/GetChartData',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
        if(jqXHR.status==200){
            alert(jqXHR.status);
            $('#graphContainer').highcharts(data[0]);
        }
        if(jqXHR.status==500)
            alert("Fail");                      
    }
});
}
```